# How to quickly access print-preview in Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, printing, shortcuts, preview

Is there any way to access print preview without going through "menu firefox -> menu print -> print preview"? Preferably keyboard shortcut, or a way to add print-preview icon to my toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up firefox Use Alt + f then v as a keyboard shortcut

Comment: not bad, but was hoping for something that works in one step.

Comment: Still working in version 49, which is even more helpful, since the menus no longer appear (at least by default).